# Iterate If statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 12 modals. I want to compare each modal's `.modal__content` height to the `viewport height`, and if a particular modal `.modal__content` height is < than `vh` `addClass("center")` to it `else` `addClass("margin")`, then go to the next modal - compare it, do the `if` statement and so on till the last modal.

Each modal has the same class `.modal__content`.

This is my `if`:

```
  if ($(window).height() > $('.modal__content').actual('height')) {
    $('.modal__content').addClass("center");
  } else {
    $('.modal__content').addClass("margin");
  }
```

Example of a modal:

```
  <div class="modal" id="modal-3"> // each modal has it's own id
    <div class="modal__content">
      <h3>Heading</h3>
      <div>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
        <button class="md-close">close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Questions:**

1) In which kind of loop should I place my `if`? Mb I don't need loop at all?

2) `$('.modal__content').addClass("center");` - is ***implicit iteration*** how can I limit it only to a particular modal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it like

```
$('.modal__content').each(function(){
 if ($(window).height() > $(this).actual('height')) {
    $(this).addClass("center");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("margin");
  }
})
```

Comment: Happy Coding ! Please accept the answer if it worked (y)